# How to call one method from another method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, scope, structure

I would like to know if the way I have **assigned values to the 'Deval' and 'Reval' variables in the 'datevalidate' method**   is correct?

If you notice my code, I am assigning values by specifying the entire chain pointing to the method like so '**x9.validator.check_element_val()**'. Can I make a less explicit call? Since I am trying to access a function outside the immediate lexical scope of these variables, **is there some way I can use a closure to better approach this**?

Kindly correct my understanding of closures if it is not apt for the current scenario.

```
var x9 = {} || x9;
x9.validator = {
mode : 1,
check_element_val : function(el){
    var returnval = 0;
    if (el.value == 0 || el.value == undefined || el.value == null || el.value == ''){
        returnval = 0;
    }else{
        returnval = 1;
    }
    return returnval;
},
datevalidate : function(mode, dep_el, ret_el){
    var returnobj = new Object();
    if (mode == 1){
        Deval = x9.validator.check_element_val(dep_el);
        Reval = x9.validator.check_element_val(ret_el);
        if (Deval == 0 || Reval == 0){
            returnobj.returnval = false;
        }else{
            returnobj.returnval = true;
        }                   
    }
    return JSON.stringify(returnobj);
}
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this code work or not ? What you're trying to achieve here is not really OOP. it's more like using object literals as real object. Do you need something more OOP ?

Comment: The above code is working perfectly fine, but yes I would like a more OOP way of structuring this.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hqrrwegk/1/ ? ;-)

Comment: @Su4p yes correctly identified the pattern there, it is more of object literal. I like the suggested Module pattern by another user.

Comment: @Nico your approach is fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you would benefit from the [Module](http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/) pattern (see this [simple example](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/#the-module-pattern)). You could do something like this:

```
var x9 = {} || x9;
x9.validator = (function() {

    var mode = 1;

    var check_element_val = function(el){
        var returnval = 0;
        if (el.value == 0 || el.value == undefined || el.value == null || el.value == ''){
            returnval = 0;
        }else{
            returnval = 1;
        }
        return returnval;
    };

    var datevalidate = function(mode, dep_el, ret_el){
        var returnobj = new Object();
        if (mode == 1){
            Deval = check_element_val(dep_el);
            Reval = check_element_val(ret_el);
            if (Deval == 0 || Reval == 0){
                returnobj.returnval = false;
            }else{
                returnobj.returnval = true;
            }                   
        }
        return JSON.stringify(returnobj);
    }

    return {
        mode : mode,
        check_element_val : check_element_val,
        datevalidate : datevalidate
    };
})();
```

As a side note, I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the `mode` variable, but be aware that the `datevalidate` function will not be using it unless you supply it yourself as an argument, for instance:

```
var validation = x9.validator.datevalidate(x9.validator.mode,someValue1,someValue2);
```

If you want the function to only use the `mode` variable from within the validator, remove `mode` from the argument list. If you want to keep the ability to provide different modes, though, you can write an additional function. For example:

```
var datevalidate_default_mode = function(dep_el,ret_el) {
    return datevalidate(mode, dep_el, ret_el);
};
```

I think it looks nicer than adding `x9.validator.mode` to the `datevalidate` function every time you want to use the default value. And that way you can even remove `mode` from the module output. Either way, if you're adding a new public function, don't forget to expose it in the module output as well!

Comment: Alan Fluka . thanks for the reply. Appreciate the detailed answer there. I like the suggested approach to pass the 'mode'.